# What is the app which let user to find by finding application and files with key combinations?

Tags: macos

I am not a mac power user and when ever I need to find an application or file, I open Finder and look for it. Couple of weeks ago, I saw someone using some keyboard shortcut, which opened a dialog box, where as he enters the name, the application showed the files matching the word he is searching. Is this a mac power tool or is this a different app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotlight is a part of OS X. The default keyboard shortcut is, I think, Command-Space for the Spotlight menu entry and Option-Command-Space for the Spotlight field in a Finder window. (Clarified after Chris' answer.)

There is also a third party application named Quicksilver.

Answer (score 1):

The default keyboard shortcut for Spotlight is Command-Space. See http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2531

Comment: @carsten Thanks for clarifying your answer; I had remapped Option-command-space to a different command (switching keyboard layouts), so that didn't trigger any form of Spotlight when I tried it.